# select content in html dom by class name with php

Tags: php, html, dom

I would like to pick up the contents, included in html tag with a particular class, how can I do it with php? i have write code with pquery,
but the result does not work and gives me all the site content

```
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$ch = curl_init("http://www.hosteltur.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);



$html = $content;

$dom = pQuery::parseStr($html);

$dom->query('.article-news');


echo $dom->html();
```

Answer (score 0):

To find HTML for the element having certain class below code will help.

```
$dom->query("//*[contains(@class, '.article-news')]");
echo $dom->html();
```

Comment: gives me this error:
Notice: Invalid search pattern(2): No conditions found! in C:\xampp\htdocs\pquery\gan_selector_html.php on line 392